# How to exit a while loop that uses numbers with a character that doesn't mess up the math

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, math, while-loop

I have a script to write that is able to take user input of however many numbers they want until they press "q".  Now I have it working, but it takes q and uses it in the math that the other numbers should be being used in.  It also uses it to show what is the highest or lowest number.

```
total=0
count=0
largest=num
smallest=num
while [ "$num" != "q"
do
      echo "Enter your numbers when you are done enter q"
      read num
      total=`expr $total + $sum`
      count=`expr $count + 1`
      if [ "$num" > "$largest" ]
            then
                   largest=$num
      fi
      if [ "$num" < "$smallest" ]
      then
                   smallest=$num
      fi
done
avg=`expr $total / $count`
echo "The largest number is: $largest"
echo "The smallest number is: $smallest"
echo "The sum of the numbers is: $total"
echo "The average of the numbers is: $avg"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't checking if the *first* value of `num` is "q" before attempting to use it as a number. The easiest thing to do is write an "infinite" loop with an explicit `break`; this avoids needing two separate `read` commands.

`>` and `<` are for string comparisons (and need to be escaped when used with `[`); use `-gt` and `-lt` instead.

You also do not need to use `expr` for integer arithmetic. For the average, you'll need to use `bc` (or some other program that can do floating-point arithmetic).

```
total=0
count=0
largest=
smallest=

while : ; do
  echo "Enter your numbers when you are done enter q"
  read num
  [ "$num" = q ] && break

  total=$(($total + $sum))
  count=$(($count + 1))
  if [ -z "$largest" ] || [ "$num" -gt "$largest" ]; then
    largest=$num
  fi
  if [ -z "$smallest" ] ||  [ "$num" < "$smallest" ]; then
    smallest=$num
  fi
done

# Avoid division by 0 and meaningless statistics if
# no numbers are entered. 
if [ "$count" -gt 0 ]; then
  avg=$( echo "$total / $count" | bc )
  echo "The largest number is: $largest"
  echo "The smallest number is: $smallest"
  echo "The sum of the numbers is: $total"
  echo "The average of the numbers is: $avg"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
total=0
count=0
largest=num
smallest=num
      echo "Enter your numbers when you are done enter q"
      read num
while [ "$num" != "q"
do
      total=`expr $total + $sum`
      count=`expr $count + 1`
      if [ "$num" > "$largest" ]
            then
                   largest=$num
      fi
      if [ "$num" < "$smallest" ]
      then
                   smallest=$num
      fi
      echo "Enter your numbers when you are done enter q"
      read num
done
avg=`expr $total / $count`
echo "The largest number is: $largest"
echo "The smallest number is: $smallest"
echo "The sum of the numbers is: $total"
echo "The average of the numbers is: $avg"
```